# How to Calculate A to the power B without use of multiplication and divsion operator?

Tags: c++

I need to find A raise to the power b, simply power ( a, b ) without the use of multiplication and division operator

Ex: pow ( 2, 3 ) = 8

I am unable to understand the intuition behind this code.

```
int pow(int a, int b)  
{  
    if (b == 0)  
        return 1;  
    int answer = a;  
    int increment = a;  
    int i, j;  
    for(i = 1; i < b; i++)  
    {  
        for(j = 1; j < a; j++)  
        {  
            answer += increment;  
        }  
        increment = answer;  
    }  
    return answer;  
}
```

Comment: The loop on `j` multiplies `answer` by `a` because it starts with `answer` and `increment` equal to each other and then adds `increment` `a-1` times. So, when it is done, `answer` is `a` times the value it started with. Then `increment = answer;` resets `increment` and `answer` to be equal to this new value of `answer`. The loop on `i` repeats that `b` times. Since `answer` is initially started with the value `a`, the complete effect is to multiply by `a` `b` times, which is the definition of `a` to the power of `b`.

Comment: To avoid multiplication, note that  3 x 5  means either  3+3+3+3+3  or  5+5+5.    
Also, 2 ^ 3  (i.e. 2 cubed)  means  2 x 2 x 2, which can be expanded using the additions.

Comment: This is classic bottom up development: you implement multiply first if you need it but don't have it.

Comment: In C++, _you have a multiplication operator_.  There's no good reason not to use it.

Answer (score 2):

well the inner loop multiplies a by itself by adding it to itself a times.

the outer loop does this b times

Answer (score 1):

It works like this:

If the exponent is zero you just return 1. Otherwise you need to do a calculation.

The inner loop, i.e.

```
for(j = 1; j < a; j++)  
{  
    answer += increment;  
}
```

performs a multiplication. The result of executing that code is equivalent to

```
answer += increment * a;
```

And the outer loop is repeating that multiplication b - 1 times (because answer starts as a, so you need one less multiplication as if you were starting with answer = 1), I.e. in total you get

```
answer += ((a * a) * a ) ... *a
```

for b-1 times in total, which is equivalent to a^b.

Answer (score 0):

> ...power ( a, b ) without the use of multiplication and division
>   operator

To avoid multiplication, note that 3 x 5 means either 
    3+3+3+3+3 
or 
    5+5+5.

For power, note that 3 ^ 3 (i.e. 3 cubed) means 3 x 3 x 3.  The multiplications in this product can be replaced with additions (i.e. 3 x 3 => 3+3+3, and then 9 x 3 = 9+9+9 = 27).

Answer (score 0):

```
///only for base and exponent natural numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....)
//this solution has no multiplications and no divisions :)
//for education purposes
#include <stdio.h>

double power(double base, double exponent){
  ///To understand 2^5
    int result1=0,result=0;
  //first we calculate the square of the number: 2^2=2+2
    for(int j=0;j<base;j++){
        result1=result1+base;
     }
     if(exponent==2){//if exponent equals 2, we already have the solution
         result=result1;
     }
     if(exponent==1){//if exponent equals 1, the solution is the base
         result=base;
     }
     if(exponent==0){//if exponent equals 0, the solution is 1 
         result=1;
     }
  //with two for cycles we do the job for exponents higher than 2
  //right this:
//2^2=2+2
 //2^3=2(2+2)
  //2^4=2(2(2+2))
     for(int i=0;i<exponent-2;i++){//we iterate for exponents higher than 2
         result=0;///we reset the result first
         for(int k=0;k<base;k++){
             result=result+result1;
         }
         result1=result;
       //result1 will be equal to 2^3, 2^4 and in the final to 2^5
       //we save result in the variable result1 and reuse it in the inner for cycle
     }
     return result;
}

int main()
{
   do{
    int base=0;
    int exponent=0;
    printf("\n\nEnter the base:\n");
    scanf("%d",&base);
    printf("Enter the exponent:\n");
    scanf("%d",&exponent);
    printf("=%G",power(base,exponent));
    }while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).